# Ionic input and select side by side

Tags: ionic-framework

I have one input and one select that i want to show side by side.

I attempted several way with no avail.

The current code is as follows

```
<form name="signup">
<ion-list>
<label class="item item-input">
<input placeholder="Identificación" name="identificacion" type="text" ng-click="registro.msg = null" ng-model="registro.identificacion" required>
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-select" name="tipo_id" ng-model="registro.tipo_id">
<div class="input-label">Tipo de Identificación</div>
<select ng-model="registro.tipo_id">
<option ng-repeat="tipo in defaultTipo" value="{{tipo.id}}" ng-selected="{{tipo.selected}}">{{tipo.tipo}}</option>
</select>
</label>
</ion-list>
</form>
```

This outputs the following:

[image]

I need to put the input on the left and the select on the right in the same row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the ionic grid system, but putting them side by side wont leave you a lot a room on a phone. You can read more about it here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-explicit

```
<form name="signup">
<ion-list>
**<div class="row">**
**<div class="col">**
<label class="item item-input">
<input placeholder="Identificación" name="identificacion" type="text" ng-click="registro.msg = null" ng-model="registro.identificacion" required>
</label>
</div>
**<div class="col">**
<label class="item item-input item-select" name="tipo_id" ng-model="registro.tipo_id">
<div class="input-label">Tipo de Identificación</div>
<select ng-model="registro.tipo_id">
<option ng-repeat="tipo in defaultTipo" value="{{tipo.id}}" ng-selected="{{tipo.selected}}">{{tipo.tipo}}</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</ion-list>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I have a related question, but posted a new question as it is related yet different, but maybe you can help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015930/ionic-select-no-label

Answer (score 3):

You can try this ::

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
   <ion-col width-50>
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary">Inline Label</ion-label>
    <ion-input placeholder="Text Input"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
 </ion-col>
 <ion-col width-50>
    <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Minute 2</ion-label>
       <ion-select [(ngModel)]="inr">
       <ion-option value="h1">5</ion-option>
       <ion-option value="h2">6</ion-option>
       <ion-option value="h3" >7</ion-option>
       </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W46oI.png)There is an easy way to do this. 
Just need to use an item, item-end and item-start.
then just add a line of CSS.

```css
    .input-cover{
        width: 0%;
    }
```

```html
    <ion-item *ngFor="let telefono of cliente.telefonos;index as i;trackBy:identify">
      <ion-select item-start placeholder="Celular" name="tipo" [(ngModel)]="telefono.tipo">
        <ion-option>Celular</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Casa</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
      <ion-input type="tel" item-end placeholder="Numero" name="numero" [(ngModel)]="telefono.numero"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: what if you want to add a `ion-label`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use item-input-inset class

```
    <form name="signup">
  <ion-list>
    <div class="item-input-inset">
      <div>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input placeholder="Identificación" name="identificacion" type="text" ng-click="registro.msg = null" ng-model="registro.identificacion" required>
        </label>
      </div>
      <label class="item item-input item-select" name="tipo_id" ng-model="registro.tipo_id">
        <div class="input-label">Tipo de Identificación</div>
          <select ng-model="registro.tipo_id">
            <option ng-repeat="tipo in defaultTipo" value="{{tipo.id}}" ng-selected="{{tipo.selected}}">{{tipo.tipo}}</option>
          </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```