# Ionic 5 form layout - How do I put input and select side-by-side

Tags: html, ionic-framework, mobile

This question was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008491/ionic-input-and-select-side-by-side), but the solution was several years old and not well-suited for me since it's an earlier version of Ionic.  I want to put City and State next to each other as an ion-input (with a floating label) and an ion-select (no label). Below is my HTML and the resulting display:
[![Result][1]][1]

````
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="8">
      <ion-item lines="full">
        <ion-label position="floating">City</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="4">
      <ion-item lines="full">

        <ion-select placeholder="State">
          <ion-select-option [value]="st" *ngFor="let st of [{ name: 'Louisiana'},{name: 'Texas'}]">{{st.name}}
          </ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>

      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>```
  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Hqj.png
````

Comment: Sorry, I hope you can see my image. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Hqj.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Hqj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ion-label` with stacked position on your select options.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="8">
        <ion-item lines="full">
          <ion-label position="floating">City</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>


      <ion-col size="4">
        <ion-item lines="full">
          <ion-label position="stacked">City</ion-label>
          <ion-select placeholder="State">
            <ion-select-option [value]="st" *ngFor="let st of [{ name: 'Louisiana'},{name: 'Texas'}]">{{st.name}}
            </ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>

        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Comment: Perfect!  I had to adjust some padding and hide the stacked label, but everything lines up perfectly now.  Thanks, Najam!  I appreciate the quick help.